# How do I view the Bind variables from a PHP Prepared Statement on SQL Server 2012?

Tags: php, sql-server, prepared-statement

I have read the SO question about Oracle's Bind equivalent.  This is four years later, however.  I have looked at sp_executesql from

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I am not using T-SQL or any sort of Stored Procedure, only a PHP Prepared Statement (using PDO).

How can I view my bound value in SQL Server 2012?  If there is a way for me to use sp_executesql, I do not know how to use it.

EDIT:  When I say view, I mean a table in SQL Server.

EDIT:  I am trying to find out the value that was received by SQL Server.  I want to query a view, table, run a stored procedure, something so I can see what SQL Server actually received.

Here is a similar question:
[What is the SQL Server equivalent of Oracle bind variables in dynamic SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898611/what-is-the-sql-server-equivalent-of-oracle-bind-variables-in-dynamic-sql)

This is what it is in Oracle 11g:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2114.htm#REFRN30310

"V$SQL_BIND_CAPTURE displays information on bind variables used by SQL cursors. Each row in the view contains information for one bind variable defined in a cursor. This includes:"

EDIT:
Example,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees where employeeid = :mykey";
$prepared_statement = $this->_adapter->prepare($sql);
$prepared_statement->bindValue(':mykey', $_employee_search, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepared_statement->execute();
```

I wan to know `:mkey` after it has been sent to SQL Server.

Comment: View where? in your code after the statement is prepared or anywhere for debugging?

Comment: This question is unclear: What exactly do you want to do? The way this is worded it seems as though you either need to simply read PHP variables for read from the database after the statements have been executed.

Comment: I added an edit.  I want to look at the data in the database that was received, what SQL Server saw.  I do not want anything emitted by the script to echo or anything like that.

Comment: MySQL has something called general query log. I'm not sure about SQL Server though, but [could this help by any chance](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/can-i-see-historical-queries-run-on-a-sql-server-database)?