# Update column with inner join and string interpolation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update a table1 column with a string that has table2 column interpolated inside.

I'm not sure how string interpolation is done.

```
UPDATE p
SET p.ImagePath = i.img_id --> Here I want something like $"some/url/{i.img_id}" to update the column
FROM dbo.Player AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.Images AS i
ON p.p_id = i.img_event_player_id
where i.img_type = 1
```

I expect the `dbo.Player.ImagePath` column to be `some/url/4555` for example.

Comment: If the URL is a parameter, maybe you can use a bind variable? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898611/what-is-the-sql-server-equivalent-of-oracle-bind-variables-in-dynamic-sql

Comment: Are youlooking for `SET p.ImagePath = CONCAT('some/url/', i.img_id)` ?

Comment: This is the expected result - https://jsfiddle.net/pwjeL9xv/

Comment: Put the details in your post as `text` @duckhead, with sample data **and** expected results. Please don't link to an off site resource in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CONCAT()` function you can add the text `some/url/` infront of the img_id

```
UPDATE p
SET p.ImagePath = CONCAT('some/url/', i.img_id)
FROM dbo.Player AS p
INNER JOIN dbo.Images AS i ON p.p_id = i.img_event_player_id 
WHERE i.img_type = 1
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. I don't know why I didn't get this as a first result, maybe because I tried searching for interpolation instead of concatenation.